# Subdivide multi segmented Cubic Bezier spline

Tags: bezier, spline, after-effects, cubic

First of let me apologies for a bad English and probably not very straight forward question, as I am not really sure how to call it.

I have a multi segmented Cubic Bezier curve In After Effects, it is is defined by 5 vertices with IN & OUT tangents. My task is to subdivide it into N small linear chunks in Java Script.

**EDIT submited more info.**
Given a multi segmented Cubic Bezier spline defined by 5 points with In & Out tangents, I need to get a linear representation of it. Where N is number of linear segments, defined by user.

Cubic Bezier Spline:

```
Segment1: P0, P0out, P1in, P1;
Segment2: P1, P1out, P2in, P2;
Segment3: P2, P2out, P3in, P3;
Segment4: P3, P3out, P4in, P4;
```

Expected output:

```
N = 1: linear spline with 2 anchors representing entire shape;
N = 2: linear spline with 3 anchors representing entire shape;
N = 3: linear spline with 4 anchors representing entire shape;
N = 4: linear spline with 5 anchors representing entire shape;
...
N = 8: linear spline with 9 anchors representing entire shape;

distance(L0,L1) = distance(L1,L2) = distance(L2,L3) = ... = distance(L-n, Ln)
```

In example image I use 4-segmented spline, where segment length is equal to one another - this is just easier to draw to explain my task. But in real project those segments will not be equal, and there will be more then 4 segments total.

[image]

I have looked at [de Casteljau](http://www.antigrain.com/research/adaptive_bezier/index.html#toc0003) method, but as I can understand, it works with one segment spline. My math skills are dusty, so I am not really sure if I can use de Casteljau in my example.

Comment: Might [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347115/convert-bezier-curve-with-n-point-to-many-cubic-bezier-curve?rq=1) be the same issue?

Comment: Well, I do not need to subdivide original spline to cubic bezier splines, I only need to get a linear representation of it. So precision doesn't matter.

Comment: Apply deCasteljau algorithm as many times as you want to the first segment (eg: 3 times will produce 2^3=8 subsegments), then same thing to the second segment, etc. But your second image suggests something else:  the four segment is split into 4 subsegments, while the other two are split in only 3. If this is intentionnal then you should look for "adaptative subdivision"

Comment: Xavier, I have updated my question to better illustrate what I am after. Given a Cubic Bezier spline user will enter subdivision value N that will display a Linear Spline "trying to repeat" that original Cubic Bezier spline. The bigger the N value, the more precise representation of Cubic Bezier spline. I understand how stupid my question sounds, there's probably much better way to say what I am saying, but again, my English is not the best.

Comment: You're crucially missing what N=3 should look like. Also, *why* do you need to do this? Because it seems for more obvious to treat N as the number of points *between* your already defined points. Removing any of those five points makes no sense, we already know that they exist, and where in the plane they are, so why would we not always keep them? `N=0` makes far more sense as "the lines between our five fixed points, with `N=1` being "one point between each of those five points", `N=2` "two points between each of those five points" etc. etc. Especially since the full shape is not "one curve"

Comment: @Mike I am sorry I don't have example for N=3, it's difficult to draw. Probably main thing I forgot to mention is that distance between linear points (L0-L1-L2 etc) must be equal. So I am treating N as a number of linear segments that can define original Cubic Bezier spline. The higher N = the more precise representation of Cubic Bezier spline.       If I was adding additional points between original ones as you suggest, then the distance between L0, L1, L2 etc wouldn't be equal. Does that make any sence?

Comment: Okay, but coding it is harder than drawing it, so please draw it anyway. Also, that leaves the question "why?" are you doing this just for fun (in which case, what have to tried to code so far?), or are you doing this because it needs to be done (in which case, why would you implement this yourself, first [search and research](/help/how-to-ask) whether someone else already wrote code that does this)

Comment: Thank you @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I've updated image with additional N=3 & N=5 steps. Regarding _why_, the simplest way to explain this would be: user selects a Shape Layer (or a Mask) and enters value N. Then my code creates N number of layers/lights/nulls and distributes then on that spline. So L0, L1. L2, Ln vertices represent the position of those layers. And yes, I've beed digging forums for a few days already, and nothing similar came up. I wouldn't ask if such post existed already.

Comment: No, I mean "why are *you* trying to do this", not "what would users do after you've made this". What is the reason for implementing this in the first place?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans subdivide given multi segmented Cubic Bezier spline to N number of linear segments. Not really sure what I can add here.

Comment: no, you keep saying *what* you want to do, not *why* you want to do this. Did someone ask you to write this code? Is it homework? Is this a personal project where you want to explain something in illustrator, *why are **you** trying to implement this*? (if google translate cooperated, "Kodėl norite tai padaryti" not "ką jūs norite daryti")

Comment: This is my personal project. No one asked me to do this - I just realised I want to do it. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

This is conceptually straight forward, although it might involve quite a bit of code for reasons explained a little later on. What you're trying to do is flatten a (cubic) [poly-Bezier](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#polybezier), so let's start with that:

Individual cubic Bezier curves are generated by four points: a start point, a control point that determines the tangent at the start point, an end point, and a control point that determines the tangent at the end point. The curve, then, is a plot of the cubic Bezier function:

```
Bx(t) = p1.x × (1-t)³ + 2 × p2.x × (1-t)² × t + 2 × p3.x × (1-t) × t² + p4.x × t³
By(t) = p1.y × (1-t)³ + 2 × p2.y × (1-t)² × t + 2 × p3.y × (1-t) × t² + p4.y × t³
```

A single Bezier curve is plotted over the interval `t=[0,1]`, so a poly-Bezier of N segments is plotted over a total interval `N × [0,1]`.

First, the simple case: simple flattening. Bezier curves are non-linear curves and so let's first not bother to enforce "same length for each of the line segments". Given an N-segment poly-Bezier:

```
S = number of segments we want
points = empty list
for (s = 0):(s = S):(step = S/N):
  v = s * step
  segmentid = floor(v)
  segment = polycurve.segments[segmentid] 
  t = v % 1
  points.push(
    segment.pointAt(t)
  )
```

We now have all the points we need, and we just connect them with lines. Done.

However, Bezier curves are non-linear curves, so flattening in this way does not yield equidistant segments in the slightest. If we want to do that, we need to work with [distance along the curve](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing) rather than `t` values.

```
S = number of segments we want
points = empty list
for (s = 0):(s = S):(step = S/N):
  v = s * step
  segmentid = floor(v)
  segment = polycurve.segments[segmentid]
  distanceRatio = v % 1
  t = segment.getTforDistanceRatio(distanceRatio)
  points.push(
    segment.pointAt(t)
  )
```

This will work exactly as you want, but `getTforDistanceRatio` is the hard part, because what we're doing here is reparameterizing the curve for distance, rather than time, and that is a *very hard* mathematical problem (for which no general symbolic solution exists). The cheapest way to do this is using a Lookup Table (LUT), which is explained in the link above, for "distance along the curve".

Comment: Thank you Mike for your detailed reply. Appreciate this very much. Your second code is what I need exactly. Will be reading about distance along the curve. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The de Casteljau method is used to compute a point on the Bezier curve and also obtain the control points for the two subdivided curves in the process. So, yes you should be able to use de Cateljau method to evaluate as many points as you want on a Bezier curve if you know the control points.

From the picture you show and the fact that your "cubic Bezier spline" takes in/out tangents as input, I think your spline is actually "cubic Hermite spline", in which each segment is indeed a cubic Bezier curve. You can convert each segment of your spline to a cubic Bezier curve, then use de Cateljau method to evaluate as many points as you want, then connect these points by straight lines.

Comment: I am able to split each segment and use de Casteljau on them, but my main taks is to get equal length between those new points. Like when N=3. Distance between L0=L1, distance between L1=L2.

Comment: OK. It is my misunderstanding. Look like your real requirement is for that approximating linear spline to have equal length for all segments.  This is different from the usual "equal distance along the curve" requirement.

Comment: Imposing conditions on the cord lengths L0L1=L1L2=L2L3, etc, gives some ill-defined problem. For instance if N=2, you could split the curve at any point on the bisector of the segment [first vertext of the curve, last vertex of the curve]. There can be many such points, and it's non trivial to decide which should be the best. You should stick to conditions on arc lengths imo.